# Unable to make dtype converson from object to str

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, str-replace

```
       loan_amnt    funded_amnt   funded_amnt_inv    term   
0        5000.0       5000.0           4975.0      36 months    
1        2500.0       2500.0           2500.0      60 months
```

My dataframe frame goes like above .

I need to change '36 months' under term to '3'(months to years) but I'm unable to do so as the dtype of 'term' is Object.

loan.term.replace('36months','3',inplace=True) -->No change in dataframe

I tried the below code for type conversion but it still returns the dtype as Object

loan['term']=loan.term.astype(str)

Expected output:

```
       loan_amnt    funded_amnt   funded_amnt_inv    term   
0        5000.0       5000.0           4975.0          3    
1        2500.0       2500.0           2500.0          5
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated .Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in a variable like data, use this:

```
for i in data:
    i['term'] = int(i['term'].split(' ')[0])//12

print(data)
```

you'll get your output!

Comment: Thanks Abhay , although I wanna make changes in my dataframe itself and not print them